# want to use windows container server in circleci

Tags: travis-ci, circleci, appveyor

Current project is using windows server.

The request from client was automation test using circle ci.
but when I check circleci document, it may be impossible to deploy windows server(windows docker container)

https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015871087-Windows-and-NET-Support
https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/faq/

Is there a way to deploy windows docker container in circle ci?
Or do I have to search other CI service like https://www.appveyor.com/ ?